# Strapi v3 to v4 migration "Could not find field size for custom plugin"

Tags: strapi

After migrating strapi application from v3 to v4 I am getting an error on custom plugin "Could not find field size for specialistpicker". Hear specialistpicker is our custom plugin.
[strapi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1yYW.png)

I am using codemods to migrate the strapi application.
Strapi V3 package.json
[Strapi V3 package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FivoC.png)
Strapi V4 package
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNzxM.png)

Comment: facing the same error on ApplicationError: Could not find field size for type [object Object], but seems like it's on node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/field-sizes.js:62:15)
shared on Strapi looking for a solution.